# ORACLE SQL Query for related rows

Tags: sql

I have a situation where all the information I need is in a single table, and one of the columns contains values that are the 'parent' values for the ones in a different column. I would need to obtain the code for the parent value. Here is the table:

```
NAME            ORGANIZATION_ELEMENT_ID              CODE    IMMEDIATE_PARENT_ID 

Company_Name1   1f671a2d8a4a40f8be4fa54500db025f     F750    e9ec0f42b1714921a491a5d000fa4fff
Company_Name2   10b4acbbf8864c22ac23a54500da401c     F161    7d205877767047f3a971a5d000fad2e6
Company_Name3   s9ddg9asdf7s5s78gd7dsg6sag9sdsh9     F111    10010f1417ff44ce9908bf381687fc63
Company_Name4   e9ec0f42b1714921a491a5d000fa4fff     F150    e9ec0f42b1714921a491a5d000fa4fgh
Company_Name5   7d205877767047f3a971a5d000fad2e6     F160    7d205877767047f3a971a5d000fad2e5
Company_Name6   10010f1417ff44ce9908bf381687fc63     F170    10010f1417ff44ce9908bf381687fc62
Company_Name7   e9ec0f42b1714921a491a5d000fa4fgh     F180    e9ec0f42b1714921a491a5d000fa4fgg    


The output would have to be similar to:

NAME           ORGANIZATION_ELEMENT_ID            CODE  IMMEDIATE_PARENT_ID           PARENT_CODE

Company_Name1  1f671a2d8a4a40f8be4fa54500db025f   F750  e9ec0f42b1714921a491a5d000fa4fff F150
Company_Name2  10b4acbbf8864c22ac23a54500da401c   F161  7d205877767047f3a971a5d000fad2e6 F160 
Company_Name3  s9ddg9asdf7s5s78gd7dsg6sag9sdsh9   F111  10010f1417ff44ce9908bf381687fc63 F170
Company_Name4  e9ec0f42b1714921a491a5d000fa4fff   F150  e9ec0f42b1714921a491a5d000fa4fgh F180
Company_Name5  7d205877767047f3a971a5d000fad2e6   F160  7d205877767047f3a971a5d000fad2e5 ...
Company_Name6  10010f1417ff44ce9908bf381687fc63   F170  10010f1417ff44ce9908bf381687fc62 ...
Company_Name7  e9ec0f42b1714921a491a5d000fa4fgh   F180  e9ec0f42b1714921a491a5d000fa4fgg ...
...            ...                                ...   ...                              ...
```

There shouldn't be any null values for org_elem_id, so eventually all parent codes will have values.

If any additional details are needed, please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database that you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want a `left join`:

```
select t.*, tp.code as immediate_parent_code
from t left join
     t tp
     on t.IMMEDIATE_PARENT_ID = tp.ORGANIZATION_ELEMENT_ID
```

Comment: Thank you! If one of the columns were calculated, and not part of the table itself, would it still work? Meaning that I get "immediate_parent_id" by using SUBSTR on another column that is actually in the table.

Comment: @aramamihai . . . You can use an expression in the `on` clause.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of self join.  You can join the same table on t1.immediate_parent_id  = t2.organization_element_id